# remove extra price from dropdown in configurable product

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

please see here [image]

how to remove that from drop-down?
while at the same time if we choose this option the original price will change as well.

Answer (score 1):

in order to remove that additional price entirely you have to over write functionality of below script:

/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php

GO to line number : 70 and change the code with this code snippet :

From :

```
$select->addOption(
            $_value->getOptionTypeId(),
            $_value->getTitle() . ' ' . $priceStr . '',
            array('price' => $this->helper('core')->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false))
        );
```

To :

```
$select->addOption(
            $_value->getOptionTypeId(),
            $_value->getTitle() /*. ' ' . $priceStr . ''*/,
            array('price' => $this->helper('core')->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false))
        );
```

you will find workaround this block, hope it will help

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply
I do that but it didn't worked

Comment: make sure your overridden code is working and file is being called, however if that doesnet work then you would also need to change in js file : check this link https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-remove-price-in-product-option.html

Comment: doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I registered just to say thank you to Naveed. I was going to just add a comment on their post, but I can't as a new user. So to anyone wanting the correct answer, his answer is correct except there is a space in his code causing it to not work.

```
$select->addOption(
        $_value->getOptionTypeId(),
        $_value->getTitle() /*. ' ' . $priceStr . ''*/,
        array('price' => $this->helper('core')->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false))
    );
```

Should be

```
$select->addOption(
        $_value->getOptionTypeId(),
        $_value->getTitle()/*. ' ' . $priceStr . ''*/,
        array('price' => $this->helper('core')->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false))
    );
```